# How to get ordered quantity from product?

Tags: magento-1, product-collection, quantity

I'm trying to get the ordered quantity from my `catalog/product` collection, but I'm having this error:

> Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addOrderedQty()

Here is my code:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addOrderedQty('', '');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    return $this;
```

How can I solve this and get the ordered quantity on my collection? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because these is no function named as addOrderedQty in catalog/production collection

if you want to fetch specific product ordered qty you can use below code:

```
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->getFirstItem();
echo 'Already Bought ' . (int) $product->ordered_qty;
```

if you don't want to specify sku you can comment out this line

```
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I need to get certain attributes from 'catalog/product' on my grid + their ordered_qnty. How could I do that?

Comment: The answer was to put ->addAttributeToSelect('*') and exclude null values on filter. Thanks for the help with the reports. +1